# How to tell a View subclass to load its own layout

Tags: android

I have a custom View subclass which I am calling `ListItem` which has a layout (`res/layout/list_item.xml`). I cannot get my `ListItem` class to load the layout xml file.

```
public class ListItem extends View{

    private TextView title, subtitle;

    public ListItem(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public ListItem(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public ListItem(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);

        //I want to load/inflate the view here so I can set title and subtitle.
    }
}
```

I can get the view to load by doing this, but I don't like the fact that it happens outside of the scope of the `ListItem` class. It seems like `ListItem` should be responsible for loading its own view. From ListViewAdapter.java:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ListItem entry = items.get(position);
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
    }

    TextView title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
    title.setText(entry.getTitle());

    TextView subtitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.subtitle);
    subtitle.setText(entry.getSubtitle());

    return convertView; 
}
```

Again, I want to load the layout from within the `ListItem` class. Is it possible for a view to load its own layout?

Comment: This is kinda backwards what you're doing. I understand your desire to do it this way (keep view stuff separate. Understandable) However, you're actually over-complicating things and adding an extra class that's not needed. The way you have it in the getView you posted is EXACTLY how it should be loaded. A view shouldn't load itself. The "container" (in this case, the container is the adapter) should load the views it is using.

Comment: Just a follow up, there's technically nothing wrong with what you're doing. It will work just fine. It's simply not common practice to do this. Especially for a simple view like this.

Answer (score 1):

You got it backwards. A view does not load *a* layout; a view is loaded *from* the layout. If you want the root element of the layout to be an instance of your view, use a custom view tag in the layout: `<com.mypackage.ListItem>`.

Answer (score 0):

I usually do something like:

```
public ListItem(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View inflatedView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, this);

        TextView title = (TextView) inflatedView .findViewById(R.id.title);
        title.setText(entry.getTitle()); // entry needs to be available
        TextView subtitle = (TextView) inflatedView .findViewById(R.id.subtitle);
        subtitle.setText(entry.getSubtitle()); // entry needs to be available
    }
```

Comment: Although, i've never done this for a list item.  I sometimes do this inside a custom control or something.

Comment: I saw this solution before, but it seems wasteful to load a View (`inflatedView`) inside of another View (`ListItem`).